# Calculate hours outside normal working time

Tags: excel, time

From my sample xls(office2007) listed below. I am trying to calculate the hours worked from 17:00 onwards. could someone show me how would I write the formula to achieve this.
Many thanks...

```
Leaving Time    Arrival Time    DeliveryTime    RTB      Time per Job   hoursforDaysWork
09:30:00       11:05:00         11:15:00        11:15:00    01:45:00    12:00:00
11:15:00        12:15:00        12:30:00        13:30:00    02:15:00    
13:30:00       15:30:00         15:45:00        15:45:00    02:15:00    
15:45:00       18:15:00         18:30:00        18:30:00    02:45:00    
18:30:00       19:00:00         19:45:00        21:30:00    03:00:00
```

Comment: Sorry, but I do not at all  understand your table.

Answer (score 2):

Time in Excel is based upon parts of 24 (whole day) as explained in [this article](http://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/calculating-time-in-excel).

So assuming that you care about hours after 17:00, but not after midnight, the following should help you out:

```
=IF(C2<17/24,0,C2-17/24)*24
```

C2 is the cell the calculation is for, with 17/24 giving you the time for 17:00 (5pm). The *24 at the end converts the response to be in hours instead of partial day.

Comment: Thanks Guys for replying to me. Martin I have proved your formula and it works successfully. I have amended the formula to include the first 4 columns so the formula now reads =IF(F5:I9<17/24,0,F5:I9-17/24)*24 but I return "#Value!" I need to allow for this bunch of cells and not one specific cell to return the correct value. I don't understand why I can't use F5:i9 as there will be occasions when there will only be one row of data instead of five rows as shown above.  Many thanks.

Comment: F5:I9 is a range, and so you will probably need to use the formula against your "Return to Base" as your end of day. Don't forget to subtract out any hours after 17:00 for "Leaving Time" as well. Assuming "Leaving Time" is in A1, you could try something like "=IF(D2<17/24,0,D2-17/24)*24 - IF(A2<17/24,0,A2-17/24)*24" to figure out overtime for the first row.